# SimpleDateFormat inconsistent parsing error

Tags: java, simpledateformat

The sample code speaks for itself:

```
private void parse() throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy");

        Date started = sdf.parse("Sep/22/2004");
        // this triggers: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "May/23/2010"
        Date ended = sdf.parse("May/23/2010");
}
```

Not sure what more I can add to this. I'm trying to parse "MMM/dd/yyyy" dates, and I get inconsistent exception behavior. It feels like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @habitats Or simply: `DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);` if you don't want to change the general settings.

Comment: `DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);`

Comment: Or simply that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Guillaume: Why not write it up as an answer?

Comment: I can do that. I'm not very familiar with actually posting on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was of course locale related. Add the following:

```
sdf.setDateFormatSymbols(DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Or alternatively simply declare it with locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```